# How to get the java compiler for ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, java, jdk

I am in a Java class in my college right now, and we have to be able to compile java programs via the terminal.  I would like to keep using my Ubuntu installation for it though.  whenever I try to compile something on Ubuntu, nobody can read the program.  Says something about it not being able to read the program.  I have installed the "openjdk-7-jdk" program, which might be the issue.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!  On a side note, I would like to mention that I need to compile my programs on OS X Lion or Windows 7 in order to run them correctly...

[image: Here is a picture of what I have downloaded and what I could download instead...]

[image]

Comment: before invoking java, you need to compile your program using javac: javac ToMyDearestRachel (you might need to add .java extension if you have one) - I guess Rachel will be the second happiest girl in the world (just after mine) once it works :)

Comment: The problem is I have already used javac.  It still doesn't work on Ubuntu.

Comment: ah re read your posting - yes you should use java 6 as java 7 is not yet that common ;-) Or thell the others that java 7 is now available. The different versions of java are installed in the folder /usr/lib/jvm/whatever/bin/javac - if you intend to use another installed java compiler, just invoke the command using the complete path

Comment: Should I just uninstall java 7 if it isn't all that common anyways?

Comment: you can keep it installed, but you might want to setup the version 6 as default by redirecting the symlinks javac and java

Comment: Ah well I just removed jdk7 and installed jdk6 and it works flawlessly right now! thanks you for the suggestions! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are your colleagues are using Java 6. In that case, you have to install `openjdk-6-jdk`.

Recall that single `.java` source files are compiled using:

```
javac hello.java
```

`.class` files are executed like:

```
java Hello
```

This expects a `Hello.class` file in the current directory. If you're working in a different directory, you need to set the `-classpath` (or `-cp`) option:

```
java -cp /path/to/classes Hello
```

Comment: I am in the correct directory, it just won't run for some reason.

Comment: Try using `openjdk-6-jdk` as I suggested. It's also very unusual to share `.class` files in class. Usually, the .java source files must be submitted to the teacher (and collegues)

Comment: Yeah we have to submit the .java files, but I can't even test on my machine if the programs are actually working.  I'll try java 6.

Comment: Using the `sudo update-alternatives --config java` command, you can choose your default java program. For javac, replace `java` by `javac`

Comment: Java 6 works flawlessly!  I guess it was just too updated haha.  Thanks for the help!